# How to remove 'Too many levels of symbolic links'

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, python

I am getting the following error on ubuntu while compilig a code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 188, in handle
collected = self.collect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 105, in collect
for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 131, in list
for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 39, in get_files
yield from get_files(storage, ignore_patterns, dir)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 39, in get_files
yield from get_files(storage, ignore_patterns, dir)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 23, in get_files
directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 316, in listdir
if entry.is_dir():
OSError: [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/app/components/node_modules/@yarn_components/moment/meteor/moment.js'
ERROR: Service 'nginx' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c cd components &&   yarn &&   cd .. &&   python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput &&   true' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I have run the following command
sudo dockls -l /usr/bin
and find the following output. Any help please
[image]
I am building a docker image and it is working fine on another system but not on this server.
using ubuntu 18.04  .
[Here](https://github.com/jamshaid120/test/blob/main/outpuy) is the complete output of the file. can't be added here due to length

Comment: @guiverc please have a look at question

Comment: I think your question is [answered here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141436/too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links). Simply put, "Use the absolute path instead of the relative path".

Comment: What are the content of add-apt-repository directory ? Does anything points back to apt-add-repository ?